# CMake include path conflict between system and project headers

Tags: c++, cmake

Simple problem:

I have `/usr/include/xyz/header.h` and `/home/user/project/include/xyz/header.h`

How to tell CMake to use the local header and not the system header?

Because the system header may be another version which is not compatible with the code that I have in `/home/user/project/`.

Especially when I'm building a new version to install it later, the build fails because it's trying to use the old header that is still installed!

Comment: Perhaps CMake allows relative paths.

Comment: You can use compiler arguments such as `-nostdinc++` and specify all the include paths manually.

Comment: But then I would have to hard code include paths to /usr/include/c++/X/